# From an arrow function with a string parameter, how can I return the correct type?

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an HTML file.

```html
...
<div id="my-div"></div>
<span id="my-span"></span>
<input id="my-input">
...
```

I want to create an exported function so I can use this as so:

```js
export const getKnownElement = (id: "my-div" | "my-span" | "my-input"): HTMLDivElement | HTMLSpanElement | HTMLInputElement => {
   switch(id){
      case "my-div":
         return document.getElementById(id) as HTMLDivElement;
      case "my-span":
         return document.getElementById(id) as HTMLSpanElement;
      case "my-input"
         return document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement; 
   }
}
```

When I use this function elsewhere. I'd like to know the outcome without any additional effort.

```js
// myDiv knows it is a HTMLDivElement
const myDiv = getKnownElement("my-div")
```

How can I achieve this?

I know about [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature) but that isn't quite what I want although I have tried to simplify the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make `getKnownElement` generic and use a simple type map for the return type.

```
type ElementMap = {
  "my-div": HTMLDivElement
  "my-span": HTMLSpanElement
  "my-input": HTMLInputElement
}

const getKnownElement = <K extends keyof ElementMap>(id: K): ElementMap[K] => {
   return document.getElementById(id) as ElementMap[K]
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAogGygWygOxAWQIYRgXhgG9gYYAiZMAWgBMBLAN3IC4YAJAFUwBkARJohToQpClWoBnCNjSsO3HgGUZaIagxjKNemggBXEPK68AknsPqRwAL7BgAYwD2aSSBgBzKCADSaJwDuakga7oQAPD4wUAAeIOi0kjAA1lBgTgBm8CEiOBAAfAAU9LRsPgCUbFYYeQDaPgC6BPnEYjAATt767WgwtE4O+qEAdF4g1SAAQmCmtMW05TDYSRN1jbb2zq7uDIwEnt5+gcHCGIXadEzk5QDcji5uMNKy+2NHQRPnEs9yt-fbMF0BjCB18-g+OTOFyBhmuNyAA)

Comment: Thanks Tobias! This is actually something I reached for but I couldn't figure out the Generic signature! (I tried for ages) and `keyof` just wasn't on my radar at all.  This seems very clean!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use function overloading, which unfortunately can't be used with the `const __ = () => __;` syntax.

This also leads to some duplicate code in the method headers, but that's a small price to pay.

```
function getKnownElement(id: "my-div"): HTMLDivElement;
function getKnownElement(id: "my-span"): HTMLSpanElement;
function getKnownElement(id: "my-input"): HTMLInputElement;
function getKnownElement(id: "my-div" | "my-span" | "my-input"): HTMLDivElement | HTMLSpanElement | HTMLInputElement {
   switch(id){
      case "my-div":
         return document.getElementById(id) as HTMLDivElement;
      case "my-span":
         return document.getElementById(id) as HTMLSpanElement;
      case "my-input":
         return document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement; 
   }
}

const foo = getKnownElement("my-div");
const bar = getKnownElement("my-span");
const baz = getKnownElement("my-input");
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I unfortunately moved the goalposts before I realised your response by suggesting that I knew about function overloading.  I feel however this should be left as technically there is no reason why I can't probably use this method and you have cemented it clearly. Appreciated.